# how to display multiple drawable images in android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

i was trying to draw three images using the following code but only one image is displaying can anyone help with this

```
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score);
            d.setBounds(5, 5, 80, 80);
            d.draw(canvas);

            Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart);
            d1.setBounds(5,screenY/2, 80, 80);
            d1.draw(canvas);

            Drawable d2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paddle);
            d2.setBounds(30, 30, 80, 80);
            d2.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `drawable-list` or java class `LayerDrawable`. such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and just set to view's background or ImageView's src

you can see more infomation at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)